# Fullcalendar custom view js eventDidMount

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I made a custom view js for fullcalendar. in custom view I have js and html code like

custom-js

```
'<td class="'+ freeDay +'"><div class="med-day-semestre" ">'
                    +'<div class="med-day-semestre-dayNumber">'
                    + '<a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">'+ nameDay + currentDay +'</a>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<div class="med-day-semestre-eventBlock">'
                    + *'<a href=" ' + seg.def.url + '" class="'+ seg.ui.classNames +
                ' fc-timeline-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end event-teal-light-disabled event-block-display" ' +
                'data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" ' +
                'data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="' + seg.def.title + '<br/><small>'+ seg.def.extendedProps.subtitle +'</small>"' +
                'data-content="' + seg.def.extendedProps.description + '">' + seg.def.title +
                '</a>'*

                    +'</div>'
                    +'</div></td>';
```

how can I change  with data-toggle="popover" to use eventDidMount insteed of `<a>`

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var displayMedexactCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
//  code ....
eventDidMount: function(info) {
                if(typeof(info.event.extendedProps.description) !=  "undefined" && info.event.extendedProps.description != "") {
                    $(info.el).popover({
                        title:info.event.title+"<small class='d-block'>"+info.event.extendedProps.subtitle+"</small>",
                        content:info.event.extendedProps.description,
                        html:true,
                        placement:'top',
                        container: "body",
                        delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 },
                        trigger:'hover',
                        template:'<div class="popover fc-med-popover '+info.event.classNames[0]+'" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
                    });
                }
            },
// code...
```

Comment: Is this a bootstrap popover?

Comment: yes its bootsrap popover

Comment: Thanks. Adding bootstrap tag in case people with that experience can help you, as it seems to be more of a bootstrap issue than a fullCalendar one